# Play Framework 2.0 with Scala compilation error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, typesafe-stack

I'm new to this Play + Scala world. I'm trying to develop some examples to start diving into Play but I've encountered myself against this problem. I'm trying to define a form by means of the following statement:

```
val helloForm = Form(
    tuple(
        "name" -> nonEmptyText,
        "repeat" -> number(min = 1, max = 100),
        "color" -> optional(text)
    )
)
```

but I keep getting a "compilation error" stating that the compiler "expected class or object definition".

This code is inserted into my app/controllers/Application.scala file right after all the needed import declarations and before my `object Application extends Controller` definition. Nevertheless I've tryed moving the form declaration down the file but it's the same.
I couldn't find so much help reading Play Framework documentation since in the hello world tutorial they say "Let’s create a very simple form in the Application controller" so I assume my code should work but for some (to me) unknown reason it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, by the way, I'm working with the hole typesafe stack 2.0 (followed their installation instructions).

Comment: shame on me, I've alredy solved it. The val declaration goes inside the Application object declaration.

Comment: You can answer yourself then instead of leaving this question unanswered.